# Need help parsing string in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I am new to perl. I need help parsing below strings, I am not sure how to do it.

Sample input & expected output:

1) Simple string

```
Input: "postgres=C*/postgres" 
Expected output: ['postgres', 'C*', 'postgres']
```

2) More complex string.

```
Input: "test,""""=C/{}"=C*T/"test,""""=C/{}"
output:  ['"test,""""=C/{}"',  'C*T', '"test,""""=C/{}"']
```

Please help.

========================= UPDATE ============

I tried below Regex,it's working for simple string but it's not working properly for complex string.

```
$line = "postgres=C*/postgres";
$line1 = 'test,""""=C/{}"=C*T/"test,""""=C/{}';
if($line =~ /(.+)\=(C\*)\/(.+)/)
{
 print "$1 $2 $3";
}

if($line1 =~ /(.+)\=(C\*)\/(.+)/)
{
 print "$1 $2 $3";
}
```

Output:

```
postgres C* postgres
```

I want to separate out string in between **"=** to **/"**

But the problem is **"** is not always there in string before **=**.

I want to retrieve substring like **C** or **C*** or **C*T** or **C*x** from main string.

Comment: Explain more about how the quotes change the =.  What does the """" do? What does the next " do?

Comment: I want to parse if user has required permission before executing any SQL in postgres. So here [user="postgres",permission="C*. owner="postgres"], I am testing extreme usernames & roles as postgres allows special characters in roles & username...... So in complex string [user=' "test,""""=C/{}" ', permission="C*T", owner=' "test,""""=C/{}']

Comment: that is what, not how.  what if there are 1,2, or 3 quotes instead of 4?  does the one quote later on need to be there to keep the first = from being the delimiter?  (I don't what you to answer those particular questions; I want you to give your rules for when = is the delimiter and when it is considered just like any other character)

Comment: Just consider = as a string if it comes in user & owner otherwise it is separator

Answer (score 1):

```
(.*)=(C\*(?:T|x|))\/(.*)
```

https://regex101.com/r/wD0xU7/1

Of course, it all depends on the actual format (possible values) of the central part.

Comment: permission can be anything i just gave sample example for example C, T , C*, T*, C*T, etc so Is there any way to grab string in between =  to /.

Comment: your solutions is working if permission has C* in it  :(

Comment: You'll have to provide an exact syntax for the string you're trying to parse. If any of the parts can contain anything, obviously, there's no way to parse it.

Comment: I want to retrieve any substring like C or C* or C*T or C*x from main string inbetween = to /, Would you please suggest regex for the same ?

Comment: Is that an exhaustive list of what may appear as the middle part? You previously mentioned `C, C*, C*T, C*x`, then `C, T, C*, T*, C*T`, and now `C, C*, CT, Cx`. You need to define once and far all what you can expect. Note that you'll need to put put what you want to match between backquotes to avoid it being interpreted by SO.

Comment: Those are just examples that that privilege can be something like that.

Comment: Well, if you don't have a pattern to match, it's not going to be possible to match it!